# Preserve NSTextField Focus

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have NSTextField inside a View based NSTableView , I need to preserver first responder status after I do a [tableView reloadData] call . How can I do this ?

So far I have tried by setting the first responder during the following callback . But it does not have any effect.

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row

Also I have tried by retrieving row after I reload the data and setting the first responder. 
- (id)rowViewAtRow:(NSInteger)row makeIfNecessary:(BOOL)makeIfNecessary

Does not seems to work either .... Any help is appreciated . ..

Answer (score 0):

Implement this method of NSTextfield:-

```
 -(Bool)becomeFirstResponder
```